# PHP - Set variable is blank

Tags: php

I have a variable set, $TSID2, but yet when it is called, it returns nothing. I've tried $global with it and it still doesn't work.  I've included the relevant portion of the script with it (the problem line is the last line). I've tried changing it to several different names, trying a direct echo, etc. and nothing seems to work with it.
What's going wrong?

```
    // --------------------------
    // INSERT YOUR SENSOR IDS HERE - THIS IS FOR BOTH CHANNEL A AND B. See thread for info.
    $sensorida = 'xxxx';
    $sensoridb = 'xxxx';
    // INSERT YOUR THINGSPEAK API KEYS HERE FOR PM10 RESULTS. See thread for info, but can be found in your sensor's JSON file.
    // TSID and TSKey are for Channel A and TSI2 and TSKey2 are for Channel B.
    $TSID = 'xxxx';
    $TSKey = 'xxxx';
    $TSID2 = 'xxxx';
    $TSKey2 = 'xxxxx';
    // --------------------------
    // USE COLOR BLENDING (SHADING) LIKE PURPLEAIR DOES AS VALUE GETS NEARER TO NEXT LEVEL (1) OR JUST USE STATIC COLOR TO COLOR (0)
    $useblending = 1;
    // --------------------------
    // SHOW TIMESTAMP OF SENSOR DATA - 1= YES 0=NO
    $showtimestamp = 1;
    // TIMEZONE MUST BE IN FORMAT PHP RECOGNIZES - SEE PHP MANUALS IF YOU NEED HELP
    $timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles';
    // AVERAGE THE AQI VALUES BETWEEN CHANNEL A AND B IN ADDITION TO THE PM VALUES (1), OR SHOW BOTH SENSORS INDIVIDUALLY (0)
    $averageaqi = 1;
    // SHOW UG/M3 RESULTS TO 2 DECIMAL PLACES INSTEAD OF JUST 0 IF LESS THAN 1
    $showdecimal = 1;
    // INSERT YOUR LOCATION OR SENSOR NAME
    $sensorname = "My Sensor";
    // DISPLAY PM10 PARTICLE VALUES
    // Note: You can display the PM10 AQI value by using the variable $AQI10. Put it in some HTML.
    $showpm10 = 0;
    // --------------------------
    // SQL LOGGING MODE
    // 0 = DON'T LOG ANY RESULTS; JUST DISPLAYS THE PURPLEAIR RESULTS AS NORMAL
    // 1 = LOG THE RESULTS TO DATABASE AND DISPLAY THE PURPLEAIR RESULTS AS NORMAL
    // 2 = LOG THE RESULTS TO DATABASE AND DON'T DISPLAY ANYTHING (CRON-TYPE SCRIPT)
    //
    // Note: The AQI logged results are always combined values (A+B) like what is shown on Purpleairs site. You can change the script if you want it done differently.
    // PM values are logged as each channel.
    //
    // IMPORTANT: YOU MUST CREATE THE DATABASE AND ITS LAYOUT - A MYSQL EXPORT IS AVAILABLE IN THE THREAD.
    $logtosql = 0;
    // --------------------------
    //MYSQL PARAMETERS FOR SQL LOGGING MODES
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";
    $tbldata = "purpleairdata";

    if ($sensorida == "")
    {
        echo "No sensor ID A entered in Script source!";
        die;
    }

    if ($sensoridb == "")
    {
        echo "No sensor ID B entered in Script source!";
        die;
    }

    if ($TSID == "" || $TSID2 = "")
    {
        echo "No Thingspeak credentials entered.";
        die;
    }

    //Make sure Purpleair's Site can be reached

    $host = 'purpleair.com';
    if($socket =@ fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10)) {
        fclose($socket);    //Wer'e good
    } else {
        echo 'The PurpleAir service is currently unreachable. Try again later.';
        error_log("Could not connect to the PurpleAir servers for the script data.");
        die;
    }

    //Make sure Thingspeak's Site can be reached

    $host = 'api.thingspeak.com';
    if($socket =@ fsockopen($host, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10)) {
        fclose($socket);    //Wer'e good
    } else {
        echo 'The Thingspeak service is currently unreachable. Try again later.';
        error_log("Could not connect to the Thingspeak servers for the script data.");
        die;
    }

    //Get the sensor data via JSON
    $pajsona = file_get_contents("http://www.purpleair.com/json?show=" . $sensorida);
    $pajsonb = file_get_contents("http://www.purpleair.com/json?show=" . $sensoridb);

    //Get the PM10 value from Thingspeak
    $pm10 = file_get_contents("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/" . $TSID . "/fields/field3/last.txt?api_key=" . $TSKey);
    $pm102 = file_get_contents("https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/" . $TSID2 . "/fields/field3/last.txt?api_key=" . $TSKey2);
```

Comment: You're overwriting it in the if statement - `$TSID2 = ""`

Comment: Just saw that. SMH... Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Was being overwritten in if statement, missed an extra =.